# Pip-install with "-e" flag and VSCode module-import warnings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, type-hinting

Using Python-3.11, I have a small utility package (`ph_units`) that is needed by a new main package I am developing. I am using `pip install -e` during development to pull in that dependency while I'm working. I am using `python3 -m venv venv` to create virtual environments for all of this work.

This all works great, and any changes to the `ph_units` utility package update properly in my main package as I go. Everything runs properly with no errors or issues.

### However:

---

Even though it runs fine, I am getting warnings in my VS-Code environment about `Import could not be resolved`, and I do not get any type-hinting or autocomplete for any of my utility objects when working in my main package.

[image: VS-Code Import Error]

I suppose this makes sense, as the utility package is not actually in the `venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/` folder, but instead just the editable finder references are actually in there.

But I wonder if there is a known workaround to get proper VS-Code type-hints, autocomplete, and to avoid having VS-Code telling me there are errors when using the `-e` flag with `pip install`?

### Environment:

- Python 3.11
- MacOS Monterey 12.5.1
- VS Studio Code - Insiders v1.84.0

Comment: Please [don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add the following codes to your `settings.json` to gain intellisense:

```
  "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "path/to/your/package"
  ],
```